# how i can with just with the checked entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

**Hi,**

i just wanna ask you guys, if is there any way to work with just checked chexboxes

here it my code :

```
    from tkinter import *

window1 =Tk()
window1.geometry("400x400")
window1.resizable(False,False)
#---------------------------------------------
def test1():
    if entry1['state'] == 'normal':
        entry1['state'] = 'disabled'
    else:
        entry1['state'] = 'normal'

entry1 =Entry()
entry1.pack()
cb1 = Checkbutton(command=test1)
cb1.select()
cb1.pack()
#---------------------------------------------
def test2():
    if entry2['state'] == 'normal':
        entry2['state'] = 'disabled'
    else:
        entry2['state'] = 'normal'

entry2 =Entry()
entry2.pack()
cb2 = Checkbutton(command=test2)
cb2.select()
cb2.pack()
#---------------------------------------------
def test3():
    if entry3['state'] == 'normal':
        entry3['state'] = 'disabled'
    else:
        entry3['state'] = 'normal'

entry3 =Entry()
entry3.pack()
cb3 = Checkbutton(command=test3)
cb3.select()
cb3.pack()
#---------------------------------------------
def test4():
    if entry4['state'] == 'normal':
        entry4['state'] = 'disabled'
    else:
        entry2['state'] = 'normal'

entry4 =Entry()
entry4.pack()
cb4 = Checkbutton(command=test4)
cb4.select()
cb4.pack()
#---------------------------------------------

def message():
    b = float (entry1.get())
    c = float ( entry2.get())
    d = float ( entry3.get())
    e = float ( entry4.get())
    
    
    label1 = Label(window1, text="1) here is what you wrote ma boy :"+ str(b))
    label1.place(x=60,y=200)
    label2 = Label(window1, text="2) here is what you wrote ma boy :"+ str(c))
    label2.place(x=60,y=230)
    label3 = Label(window1, text="3) here is what you wrote ma boy :"+ str(d))
    label3.place(x=60,y=260)
    label4 = Label(window1, text="4) here is what you wrote ma boy :"+ str(e))
    label4.place(x=60,y=290)
    
button1 = Button(window1,text="Click", command= message, width=8)
button1.place(x=20,y=200)

window1.mainloop()
```

here is what i want :

i want to check the checkbox 2 and 4 for example and enter values and i want the code to execute just the second and the forth message. if i check the the first,second and the forth checkboxes,and enter values, i want the code to execute just the first, the second and the forth message. and so one . i wish u unerstand what i'm trying to say.

**thank you in advance,**
and i'm sorry for my bad English

if there is a tutorial that can help me in this , plz just share it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i will try , i want to check the checkbox 2 and 4 for example and enter values and i want the code to execute just the second and the forth message.
 if i check the the first,second and the forth checkboxes,and enter values,  i want the code to execute just the first, the second and the forth message.
and so one .
i wish u unerstand what i'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbuttons command is executed every time you click on it. The checkbutton takes additional options like `variable` a tkinter **variable** that **is set** to **`onvalue`** and **`offvalue`** depending on an internal state. Check your variable in the function and alter the entry as you desire.

**update**
*You could check the variable even in a different function like your message function.*

```
import tkinter as tk

def message():
    if var.get():
        print(entry.get())
        entry.delete('0',tk.END)

def test():
    if var.get():#check variable
        entry['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        entry['state'] = 'disabled'

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry()
var = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)#tkinter variable
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(command=test,
                             onvalue=True,
                             offvalue=False,
                             variable=var)
button = tk.Button(text='Print',command=message)

checkbutton.invoke()
##checkbutton.invoke()

button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.BOTH)
entry.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
checkbutton.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```